# Integral Change of Variables: g(x) appears twice

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus, definite-integrals, vector-fields, change-of-variable

I would like to simplify this integral, and I think I can perform a change of variables. Here's the integral. $t, y$ and $z$ are all scalars:

$$
\int_{0}^{1}f(ty,tz)\cdot z dt
$$

Note that we have a "$g(x)=tx$" and a "$g'(x)=x$'' that could be used as the basis for a change of variables. However, the $g(x)$ is applied to two arguments to $f$ (both $y$ and $z$). Perhaps I can do the following?

$$
\int_{0}^{1}f(ty,\underbrace{tz}_{g(x)})\cdot \underbrace{z}_{g'(x)} dt = \int_{g(0)}^{g(1)}f(y,v) dv
$$
Most of the change of variables rules are all about one argument, so it's not clear what I can do.

**Update**: I think I should consider $g(t)=zt$, and thus $g'(t)=z$. Thank you to @KurtG for suggesting this. Now we can write $ty=\frac{g(t)y}{z}$. I'm not yet sure how this affects the answer, but am still trying.

Comment: $ty$ is no different from $tz$ and your variable change is $t\color{red}z=g(\color{red}{t})\,.$ Then $ty=g(t)\,y/z$ and $g'(t)=z\,.$ Can you finish?

Comment: Interesting, but I don't think I see the implication. Also: If you have an insight then definitely post an official answer and I'll upvote you! Although, I think I don't follow the steps get. Still early in the morning here though...

Comment: Okay I think I might have some progress. It seems like if ty=g(t)y/z, then you can add another g(t) in the denominator so that ty=g(t)y/g(t). Then, when the change of variables goes through, both g(t)s in ty are replaced with u, cancelling out and leaving $y$. I think that's right? Anyway, I can writeup my stab at this proof now -- not sure if it's correct -- but I think you should get the credit! Feel free to write an answer below and I'll give you the upvote.

Comment: I don't need that credit. Write it up. But note that $ty$ is not $g(t)y/g(t)$ because that's obviously $y\,.$ The point is that you cannot eliminate $y$ if it does not equal $z$.

Comment: Hmm, I don't know what you mean that $ty$ is not $g(t)y/g(t)$. Is the ultimate solution not $\int_{g(0)}^{g(1)}f(y,u) du$? Or there's just a different way to show it?

Comment: Well hang on a second, maybe $ty=g(t)y/g'(t)$.

Comment: Okay, I think I have it? So $ty=\frac{g(t)y}{g'(t)}$ (as above). So we have $\int_{0}^{1}f\bigg(\frac{g(t)y}{g'(z)},g(t)\bigg)\cdot g'(t) dt$. Now doing the change of variables, I think we have: $\int_{g(0)}^{g(1)}f(uy,u) du$.

Comment: This seems like word-play.

Comment: The integral looks not quite right. I think it should be $\int_{g(0)}^{g(1)}f(uy/z,u) du$. @Aruralreader I was just asking a Japanese native speaker if she knows the word "fu yu du". The answer was unfortunately  no.

Comment: Sanity check: for $y=z$ we should se neither an $y$ nor a $z$ anymore.

Comment: Hah. Sorry for the unfortunate-looking wordplay. I'll fix some notation in the post to avoid that. But then I have some issues with @KurtG.'s suggestion ...

Comment: Oh man, I just checked @KurtG.'s suggestion with a few of numeric examples, and I think he's right.

Comment: So I think you can generalize this to $\int_{0}^{1}f(tx,ty,tz)\cdot z dt=\int_{g(0)}^{g(1)}f(ux/z,uy/z,u)du$. Right?

Comment: In fact, you can probably generalize this to: $\int_{0}^{1}f(tx_{1},tx_{2},...,t_{xN},tz)\cdot z dt=\int_{g(0)}^{g(1)}f(ux_{1}/z,ux_{2}/z,,...,ux_{N}/z,u)du$. Any reason not to @KurtG.?

Comment: No reason not to. Good idea to check numerically. I do that a lot myself.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/142385/discussion-between-abc-and-kurt-g).

Comment: Alrighty, I do think I came across a problem though. $\int_{g(0)}^{g(1)}f(uy/z,z,v)dv$. By dividing everything by z, we're assuming that z is non-zero. Do you agree @KurtG.?

Comment: I agree but this is not a problem. For $z=0$ the integral you are starting with is zero since it has $z\,dt\,.$

Comment: @KurtG. you should check out my answer below and see if you like it :)

Answer (score 1):

Thank you to the amazing @KurtG. for providing (basically) the answer in the comments. Glory belongs to him! I tried to get him to post this so he could get credit, but he declined.

Here's the idea: $g(t)=zt$, and thus $g'(t)=z$. Now we can write:
\begin{equation}
\int_{0}^{1}f(ty,tz)z, dt = \int_{g(0)}^{g(1)}f(vy/z,v), dv = \int_{0}^{z}f(vy/z,v), dv 
\end{equation}

Now, one should be mindful that $z$ coudl equal zero, which would create a division-by-zero problem with the final term on the far RHS. However, @KurtG. points out that if $z=0$, then the far LHS evaluates to zero as well (through the product with $z$).

Some interesting test cases are $f(y,z)=y+z$ and $f(y,z)=y^2+zy+z^2$. It checks out numerically.

Let me say: I wrote this problem as the bare minimum case of a larger problem, when I had a $f$ that takes a vector as an argument. The idea above generalizes to:

\begin{equation}
\int_{0}^{1}f(tx_{1},tx_{2},...,tx_{N},tz)z, dt= \int_{g(0)}^{g(1)}f(vx_{1}/z,vx_{2}/z,...,vx_{N}/z,v), dv = \int_{0}^{z}f(vx_{1}/z,vx_{2}/z,...,vx_{N}/z,v), dv 
\end{equation}
Hope I can help others in the same situation.